# How to recreate the table by the button using HTML?

Tags: html, ajax

I have two tops (top3 and top5 by the number of tightenings). I need to create table by the button from top3 if top3 has been chosen and top5 if top5 has been chosen. Pages `/users/top3` and `/users/top5` contain tables with two tops and called by AJAX. By this code, I see that tables are outputting when choosing top3 or top5, but tables don't change if I rechoose top3 or top5 and click again. How to make them rechoosable?

```
<script>
  var created = false;
  function test() {
    var chosenOption = $("select").val();
    if (!created) {
      if (chosenOption == "3")
      {
        $.ajax('/users/top3',
        {
          dataType: 'html',
          timeout: 500,
          success: function(data) {
              $("table").attr("border","1px")
              $("table").attr("created",true)
              $(data).find('tr').appendTo("table")
          }
        });
      }
      else if (chosenOption == "5")
      {
        $.ajax('/users/top5',
        {
          dataType: 'html',
          timeout: 500,
          success: function(data) {
              $("table").attr("border","1px")
              $("table").attr("created",true)
              $(data).find('tr').appendTo("table")
          }
        });
    }
    created = true;
  }
  }
</script>
<p>Top:</p>
<button onclick="test();">Вывести</button>
<select>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: what does `data` giving inside success fn do console and check .Also you have condition i.e :`!created` next time `created` will be true and it will not enter inside `if` is this what you want ?

Comment: It is not exactly what I want, but I also want to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the variable `created` and `if (!created)` statement, and then put `$("table").empty();` into the first line of the `test()` in order to clear the table before append the contents.